# Connecting to MySQL. VB Express 2008

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have created a program in VB Express 2008 for a small company to store and manipulate data. Currently we store our data using SQL Express 2008 on our work server. This runs smoothly with no known issues.

We have several employees who are very rarely in the office who now need access to the database to create reports and view information for meetings etc. It is now time to migrate the database over to MySQL!

As I am using VB Express 2008 I have no MySql References available, I read several articles and forum posts on this subject that told me to download SQL Connector .Net 5.2.7 to enable me to browse and add the MySQL.Data reference. I have tried several versions and have had no success, **if you have any suggestions on how I can find the MySQL Reference it would be much appreciated.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your middle paragraph suggests that you're going to migrate your data over to mysql because you need people to have access to it outside of your office. You know that you can set up sql express to be accessible from the outside too?

Comment: Why? You already have SQL Express, it's free, it does everything you need, and it's entirely capable of handling more than the number of users you need to support. If it ain't broke . . .

Comment: @5uperdan No, I didn't know that was possible. I'll have a quick look into it now. Thanks!

Comment: @peterG thanks pal, I assumed it would have been part of the full package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your problem? you can not add the reference? You were not very clear..
Just download http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
then you will be able to add reference for Mysql.Data to your project.

PS : Here you can find the manuals ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ )

Comment: Sorry, not very good at explaining things!.... Yes my problem is I can't add the reference for MySQL. I will give this a go now, Thanks Wanny.

Comment: The setup will ask you to choose which connector install, just select the. NET Connector. Then it will ask the values ​​for the database connection (username and password) and should create a default instance.

It will also install MySQL Workbench is a fantastic tool for database management, has many functions. I love the fact that it allows you to create diagrams for the structure of the database.